# Closing Overlay In React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to debug my code but I lost right now.
Basicly I created State that open Login window and overlay that are Portals, when someone click the login button. its works fine but my problem is that I want when someone click on the overlay that the login window and the overlay will close.
I can't achieve that unfortunately.

Thanks For Advance !

Here is the code :

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./components/Elements/Home";
import Footer from "./components/UI/Footer";
import NaviBar from "./components/UI/NaviBar";
import "./App.css";
import Auth from "./components/Auth/Auth";

function App(props) {
  const [openWindow, setOpenWindow] = useState(false);

  const clickImport = (data) => {
    setOpenWindow(true);
  };

  const closeHandler = () => {
    setOpenWindow(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NaviBar dataClick={clickImport} />
      {openWindow && <Auth dataClickClose={closeHandler} />}
      <Home />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Auth.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import classes from "./Auth.module.css";
import Login from "./Login";
import Overlay from "./Overlay";

const Auth = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Login />, document.getElementById("auth"))}
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Overlay onClick={props.dataClickClose} />,
        document.getElementById("blur")
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Basicly I created State that open Login window and overlay that are Portals, when someone click the login button. its works fine but my problem is that I want when someone click on the overlay that the login window and the overlay will close.

Answer (score 0):

Solved It.
I forgot to update the Overlay component.

here is my fix:

```
import classes from "./Overlay.module.css";
const Overlay = (props) => {
  return <div className={classes.bgContainer} onClick={props.closeClick}></div>;
};

export default Overlay;
```